# Use Regex to remove the parentheses from "echo" calls

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ Or another tool I am looking to remove parentheses from over 500P PHP Echo calls so that the go from

```
echo('Something here')
```

to

```
echo 'something here'
```

I have tried working with `[()]` in the regex but this either remove all parentheses regardless of if there is a leading echo or removes the echo statement as well.

Comment: So, only single quoted string literals in the echo are expected? Or any kind of?

Comment: Well, `echo` is a language construct. Why are those parentheses bothering you?

Comment: This would be for Single or Double quotes. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @vivek_23 This isn't bothering me, but Sonar Qube is flagging it as a critical issue.

Comment: Try `\b(echo)\(('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")\)` and replace with `$1 $2`. *`.` matches newlines* must be turned on.

Comment: @vivek_23 `echo('');` or better yet `echo ('');` can be interpreted as an explicit expression construct because parenthesis denote that a calculation or comparison should be happening on the inside. Since `echo` is not a function call you should make your code more legible to future programmers by not using expressions when you are simply trying to output something. I would also imagine that under very specific scenarios `echo ('');` could evaluate rather than output which would be a nightmare to debug but I don't have any known examples to present. This might be why Sonar Qube is flagging it.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus is this what you are referring to (This is the example of Sonar Qube provides) `echo("Hello", "World"); // Noncompliant. Parse error`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Fair enough. Yes, `()` are usually used for some computations before we print them and this does compromise readability if we are just printing something.  Yes, that's the reason why Sonar Qube might have flagged it and it's understandable.

Comment: @CloudTheWolf I'm not sure.  That example is way different than the one you provided in your post. If you had a parse error like the Sonar Qube example then your code won't run at all. The example in your question still allows PHP to run; albeit you are missing a semi-colon at the end but I assumed that's just a typo in your question...

Comment: @CloudTheWolf Do not use regexps based on `.*?` or `.+?`, they will fail once the right hand delimiter appears inside the string itself. It is probably not very likley for the `);` to appear there but `)` is not infrequent. Once you figure it out, use my suggestion above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in Notepad++

Find what:    `echo\s*\((.*?)\);`

Replace with: `echo \1;`

- Match `echo` followed by 0 or more spaces `\s*` followed by `(` and then non-greedily match and capture everything else `(.*?)` up until a `);`.
- Replace with `echo` a space and `\1` the first capture group `(.*?)`
- You may need to adjust if there can be spaces between the `)` and `;`

This won't replace across newlines such as:

```
echo('some stuff...
      and more here... etc...');
```

However, there is a *. matches newline* checkbox when you choose *Regular expression* for the *Search Mode*.

Comment: This works until there are multiple echos on a single line. (A design flaw on my part I admit) 
```echo\s*\(([^)]*)\);``` seems to get around this.

Comment: Good catch, really I think you just need to make it non-greedy with `?`  so `.*?`.  I edited.

Comment: @CloudTheWolf I caution you to not perform a massive global replace unless you are certain about how all of the `echo();`s are constructed: https://regex101.com/r/nLzyw7/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus OP mentions [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58063386/use-regex-to-remove-remove-the-parentheses-from-echo-calls#comment102523256_58063386) they do not need to match each and every `echo` , only the ones with single and double quoted string literals inside.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am aware. Are you referring to lines 3, 5, and 6 from my regex101 link? These would cause catastrophic issues if OP blindly performs the replacements suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\becho\K\((.+?)\)`
- Replace with: `$1`  <-- there is space before $1
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary
echo        # literally
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\(          # opening parenthesis
(.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\)          # closing parenthesis
```

**Given:**

```
echo('Something here'); echo('Something 
here');
```

**Result for given example:**

```
echo 'Something here'; echo 'Something 
here';
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Find: `echo\K\((.*?')\)` replaced with: a `space $1`  a space before $1